# How do I plot the Fourier series for a square wave?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, homework

[image: Explore the Fourier Series for a square wave]

```
f (t) = (4/pi) Sum[(1/n) sin (2 pi (f (t))), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you have the function and its Fourier representation, you can try with this:

```
f[t_] = (4/Pi) Sum[(1/n) Sin[2 Pi n t], {n, 1, \[Infinity], 2}];
fserf[t_,nmax_] := (4/Pi) Sum[(1/n) Sin[2 Pi n t], {n, 1, 2*nmax-1, 2}];
GraphicsGrid[
Partition[
    Plot[{f[t], fserf[t, #]}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotLabel -> ToString[#] <> " Terms"] 
    &/@ {3, 5, 10, 20}, 2],
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

You can get your plots:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Even use `Manipulate`to interactively see how the series works:

```
f[t_] = (4/Pi) Sum[(1/n) Sin[2 Pi n t], {n, 1, \[Infinity], 2}];
fserf[t_, nmax_] := (4/Pi) Sum[(1/n) Sin[2 Pi n t], {n, 1, 2*nmax-1, 2}];
Manipulate[
   Plot[{f[t], fserf[t, nmax]}, {t, 0, scale},PlotLabel-> ToString[nmax] <> " Terms", PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}], 
{{nmax, 1, "Nº of Terms"}, 1, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{scale, 1, "x-axis length"}, 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn the proper syntax for writing Mathematica expressions. When the sum is written properly as

```
f[t_] = (4/Pi) Sum[(1/n) Sin[2 Pi n t], {n, 1, ∞, 2}]
```

> `(2 I (ArcTanh[E^(-2 I π t)] - ArcTanh[E^(2 I π t)]))/π`

then the plot is simple:

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

plot[image]